# Permission denied when trying to ssh into one virtual ubuntu machine from another

Tags: linux, ssh, remote

I'm trying to learn how to work with remote machines in linux, so I have built two ubuntu virtual machines on my PC using virtual desktop. However, I am not able to login to one machine from the other. Each virtual machine can ping the other and get a response. I also have ssh installed on both machines. When I try to login to a machine remotly, using `ssh hostname@IPAdress`, I get the following error:

```
Permission denied, please try again
```

After researching the problem by looking at a number of similar posts I can see that lots of people recommend changing various settings in the `sshd_config` file. So far, I have made the following changes:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
Password Authentication yes
```

After running the `sudo service ssh restart` command, I still get the same result.

Someone in another post suggested looking at the auth.log file. At present, the only things getting logged when I try to login are:

```
pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user by (uid=o)

pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

I'm very new to Linux, but as I understand it I am trying to login remotely to my remote user account (I only have one account, so I'm pretty sure this must be the remote user account). On my machine, you do not have to enter a password to login as this user when you first turn the machine on. But if you log out you have to enter the password to log back in. That's the password I'm using.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What exact command do you invoke to log in remotely? I guess it's `ssh …` but please be specific. Invoke it with `-v`; what does it print? Changing `sshd_config` requires restarting `sshd` or sending `SIGHUP` to it. Did you? It wouldn't work because it should be `PermitRootLogin yes` (no colon) and `PasswordAuthentication yes` (one space, no colon). I understand you're trying to log in as root. In my Ubuntu root has no password; it's impossible to log in directly as root even if `sshd` allows it, because no password can work. The lines from `auth.log` are because of `sudo`, not `sshd`.

Comment: Please do not respond in comments. [Edit] the question and add information.

Comment: In `ssh hostname@IPAdress` the string `hostname` actually specifies the user. Is your user on the remote machine named `hostname`?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue now. I was using the hostname, rather than the username to try to login.